# Confusion about the top homology group of a compact manifold.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, orientation, compact-manifolds

I know that if the manifold is compact, then all of its homology groups are finitely generated. But on the other hand, we know (for example Hatcher 3.26) that if the manifold is closed and orientable, then its top homology group $H_{n}(M; G) \cong G$. Both have relevant proofs. But how can they both be correct at the same time? If $H_{n}(M; G)$ is finitely generated and $G$ is not, then in the latter case, there would be contradiction, wouldn't it?

Comment: Did Hatcher's proof of the second assume that $G$ is f.g.?  Or maybe he only allows f.g. $G$ in $H_n(-;G)$?

Comment: @apollous01 $ℤ = ⟨1⟩$ *is* finitely generated. Are you confusing *finitely generated* with *finite*?

Comment: @k.stm yes you're right. My mistake, I just took a look at Hatcher and it's said to be true for any commutative ring as well as group.

Comment: Integral homology groups of compact manifolds are finitely generated right ? Not with coefficients in any abelian group...

Comment: @elidiot  ah I knew it was something like that, but couldn't fish it out of my memory.

Comment: Also, with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ it's clearly wrong to say the top class (or any class) is f.g.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know that if the manifold is compact, then all of its homology groups are finitely generated.

This is true for homology groups *with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$*.  As you have observed, it's obviously not true with arbitrary coefficients (there's no need to use nontrivial facts about $H_n$ to see that; just look at $H_0(M;G)$ which is trivially isomorphic to $G$ if $M$ is connected).

(More generally, if $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then $H_i(M;R)$ will be finitely generated *as an $R$-module*.  This does not necessarily mean it is finitely generated as a group.)

Comment: Thank you. I suspected the same thing, although in Hatcher there lacks any specification of such thing.